# In listing 7.15 of "Concurrency in Practice", how can both inner and outer classes synchronize on "this"?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class LogService {
  private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
  private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
  private final PrintWriter writer;
  @GuardedBy("this") private boolean isShutdown;
  @GuardedBy("this") private int reservations;
  public void start() { loggerThread.start(); }
  public void stop() {
      synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
      loggerThread.interrupt();
  }
  public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
      synchronized (this) {
          if (isShutdown)
              throw new IllegalStateException(...);
          ++reservations;
      }
      queue.put(msg);
  }
  private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
      public void run() {
          try {
              while (true) {
                  try {
                      synchronized (this) {
                          if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                              break;
                      }
                      String msg = queue.take();
                      synchronized (this) { --reservations; }
                      writer.println(msg);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ }
              }
          } finally {
              writer.close();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This is listing 7.15 from book "Java Concurrency In Practice". I can't understand how synchronization can work there. Why inner and outer class synchronize on different objects for access fields?
Is this mistake and inner class must use synchronize (LogService.this) ? Or I totally misunderstand how synchronization works?

Comment: You are right, there is a mistake here. It should be LogService.this in LoggerThread - otherwise reservations might get corrupted during modification (as -- and ++ is load, modify, store rather than atomic operation). Additionally, locks might get completely elided by smart jvm, as they are never contested (and in such case, even memory visibility might be impacted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an error in the book, listed in [the errata](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/errata.html)

> p.154: In Listing 7.15, the last two synchronized (this) lines should read synchronized (LogService.this).

Comment: ty, did't know about this link!